# Increase the counter, then reset it when a certain limit is reached

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I just started learning react and I have about a performance question. I want to increment a counter using the setInterval function and then reset it when the length of the array is reached. The problem is I need to add an `active` variable for the useEffect dependency, which removes the interval and then creates it again.

```
useEffect(() => {
     const timer = setInterval(() => {
        active == arr.length - 1 ? setActive(0) : setActive((active) => active + 1)
     }, 3000)
     return () => clearInterval(timer)
}, [active])
```

So, I wrote code like this, which looks crazy, but does the same job without removing the interval, and gets the actual version of the `active` variable from the callback.

```
useEffect(() => {
     const timer = setInterval(() => {
        setActive((active) => (active === arr.length - 1 ? active == 0 : active + 1))
     }, 3000)
     return () => clearInterval(timer)
}, [])
```

The question is how best to write and not do unnecessary work in the component

Comment: Seems both `useEffect` hooks are also missing an `arr.length` dependency. Where do these `active` and `arr` values come from?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. active is a state variable. but I really forgot to add the arr value. but this is an immutable array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably split all this logic out into a couple effects.

One to manage incrementing `active` on the interval and clearing the interval when the component unmounts.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    setActive(active => active + 1);
  }, 3000);

  return () => clearInterval(timer);
}, []);
```

A second to reset the state on the condition.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (active === arr.length - 1) {
    setActive(0);
  }
}, [active, arr]);
```

I would also caution you to protect against the edge case where `active` is updated to 0 and the `arr` array is an array of length 1 as this will trigger render looping.